# Can't upload an image to my server

Tags: linux

I would like to upload my logo image to the website. To upload it to the Linux server from my computer, i created a directory "media" in the `/var/www/html` and tried this command:

```
scp /Users/kateryna/Desktop/my_site/pics/Logo.png root@95.142.160.135:/var/www/html/media
```

After this I entered the password to the server and then nothing happened, I got an error:

> /Users/kateryna/Desktop/my_site/pics/Logo.png: No such file or
>   directory

.... even though the file exists on my machine.

Why does it happen? maybe I need to give some sort of permission? I read in one of the articles that to allow an upload, my folder permissions must be set to `777` with the command `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/upload/folder`... tried that for a different directory and didnt work either:

```
root@production-381d063e:~/new/myMedia# sudo chmod 777 /root/new/myMedia
-bash: sudo: command not found
root@production-381d063e:~/new/myMedia# chmod 777 /root/new/myMedia
root@production-381d063e:~/new/myMedia# scp /Users/kateryna/Desktop/my_site/pics/Logo.png root@95.142.160.135:/root/new/myMedia
root@95.142.160.135's password: 
/Users/kateryna/Desktop/my_site/pics/Logo.png: No such file or directory
root@production-381d063e:~/new/myMedia#
```

Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: Unix/Linux systems are case sensitive, using Tab key while you type directory names should help you reduce errors caused by key caps. The problem seems to be on your computer, that command you should type on your computer, not on server.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).